# Insertar todos los CheckedBox en una tabla base de datos ingredientes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

Estoy realizando un proyecto de una Pizzeria, el cliente podrá elegir el tipo de masa, cantidad y los diferentes ingredientes, funciona todo perfectamente menos los ingredientes que no se como hacerlo, he probado con un CheckedListBox pero no sabia como hacerlo.

Después de probar con el CheckedListBox he probado con diferentes CheckedBox porque lo que quiero es que todos los ingredientes de las pizzas aparezcan checked.

Ej Pizza 4 Quesos (ingredientes: Cheddar, Mozzarella, Emmental y Gorgonzola) el cliente puede quitar los ingredientes que no quiera.

Bueno, voy al grano, quiero que todos los CheckedBox que estén Checked se inserten en la base de datos que tengo.

He conseguido que almacene uno solo

Ingredientes es un campo Varchar y quiero que guarde todos los elementos checked separados por comas

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Pizzas (Ingredientes, Cantidad, Masa, Precio) VALUES(@Ingredientes, @Cantidad, @Masa, @Precio)", con);

            if (cbMozzarella.Checked)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ingredientes", cbMozzarella.Text);
            }
```

¿Como puedo hacer que inserte todos?

Comment: Viendo tu query, me temo que tienes algun problema básico en tu base de datos. Que es `Ingredientes? Un campo Varchar?  Y que debe ir ahi si hay cuatro ingredientes, los cuatro? Separados como, por comas? Danos algo mas de información para poder ayudarte

Comment: Perdón, Ingredientes es un campo Varchar y quiero separar todos los ingredientes seleccionados por comas para después, en un futuro hacer un carrito y que los muestre

Comment: En ese caso, es muy sencillo. Monta primero un string con los productos separados por comas, y despues añades ese string a los parámetros.

Comment: ¿Como hago un sting en cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ?

Comment: Se trata de generarlo **antes** de añadirlo a los parámetros. Mira mi respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una manera muy sencilla de generar el string con los ingredientes es usar LINQ y [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Pizzas (Ingredientes, Cantidad, Masa, Precio) VALUES(@Ingredientes, @Cantidad, @Masa, @Precio)", con);
//la siguiente línea hace lo siguiente:
//- Obtiene todos los controles del formulario que sean de tipo CheckBox
//- Mediante .Where, selecciona todos los que tengan Checked a true
//- Y de esos, selecciona su propiedad Text
var checkboxes = this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(x=>x.Checked).Select(x=>x.Text);
string ingredientes= String.Join(",", checkboxes);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ingredientes", ingredientes);
```

Para que funcione, los `CheckBox` deben estar en el `Form`. Si no es así y están por ejemplo en un `Panel`, debes acceder a la colección `Controls` de dicho contenedor.

Comment: ¿Seria una cosa así? `string ingredientes = String.Join("Mozzarella, Cheddar, Emmental", cbMozzarella.Checked, cbCheddar.Checked, CbEmmental.Checked);
                `

Comment: @ElBarto no. `String.Join` unicamente une las cadenas que que le pasas con el separador que le das como primer parámetro. No comprueba la propiedad checked ni nada de eso. Has probado el código que te he puesto tal cual?

Comment: Si pero me dice String or binary data would be truncated.

Comment: @ElBarto eso puede ser porque el tamaño de la cadena sea mayor que el de la columna. Que tamaño tiene la columna en la base de datos? y cual es el de los elementos unidos con `,`?

Comment: Lo siento si soy un poco corto pero estoy intentando aprender solo y como meta tengo realizar este proyecto

Comment: vale, tengo solo un nchar(10)...

Comment: Va perfecto, Muchisimas Gracias :)